# Flashlight windows phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, flashlight

I am a beginner who is trying to make a flashlight app for windows phone.

I have added a single button in the XAML, and this is the c#-code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraSensorLocation camLocation = CameraSensorLocation.Back;
            IReadOnlyList<object> CameraModes;
            CameraModes = AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyValues(camLocation, KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode);
            if (CameraModes.ToList().Contains((UInt32)VideoTorchMode.On))
            {
                AudioVideoCaptureDevice flashDevice;
                flashDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(camLocation, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(camLocation).First());
                flashDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The debugger breaks.
It just won't work.

If I test it on a device, the app crashes.

Comment: There is already an answer for your question [here.][1] Hope this helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259293/turn-flash-on-off

Answer (score 0):

Might this will help you. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202949%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the link that will also help you

```
    PhotoCamera cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
```

Comment: Where do I put that snippet?